# Replacing numbers in a String in java

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm trying to work out a way of safely replacing integers in a string with other strings. 
Basically the input will be a string, say "1 OR 2 AND 3". I will then also get a list of strings. In this case, it would be a list of 3 strings. For example, "Name = 1", "Name = 2" and "Name = 3".

I then need to replace the integers with the strings.

Below is an example:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class TestStringBuilder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestStringBuilder builder = new TestStringBuilder();
        String output;
        String[] filters = { "Name = 1", "Name = 2", "Name = 3" };
        output = builder.buildString(filters);
        System.out.println(output);
        output = builder.formatString(filters);
        System.out.println(output);
        System.out.println();

        /* Now swap around first two strings */
        String[] filters2 = { "Name = 2", "Name = 1", "Name = 3" };
        output = builder.buildString(filters2);
        System.out.println(output);
        output = builder.formatString(filters2);
        System.out.println(output);
        }

    private String formatString(Object[] filters)
    {
        /* Wrap integers in {} here first */
        String advanced = "{1} OR {2} OR {1}";
        return MessageFormat.format(advanced, filters);
    }

    private String buildString(String[] filters)
    {
        String advanced = "1 OR 2 OR 1";
        /*
         * Now replace the numbers with the actual filters in human readable
         * form. Note: We loop from 10 to 1 so that 10 is replaced first. If we
         * loop from 1 to 10, 1 will replace 1 and 10 incorrectly.
         */
        for (int i = filters.length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            /* Index for 0 based array */
            String filter = filters[i - 1];
            if ((filter != null) && (filter.length() > 0))
            {
                advanced = advanced.replaceAll(Integer.toString(i), filter);
            }
        }
        return advanced;
    }
}
```

First I just did a simple String.replaceAll. The problem is, if the string I'm putting in contains an integer, this may be replaced.

E.g.

I use the String array `String[] filters = { "Name = 1", "Name = 2", "Name = 3" };`

This works fine, and the output is:

`Name = 1 OR Name = 2 OR Name = 1`

However, if I use `String[] filters = { "Name = 2", "Name = 1", "Name = 3" };`

The output is incorrect, as the 1 in "Name = 1" is also replaced:

Name = 2 OR Name = Name = 2 OR Name = 2

I then tried using a java.Text.FormatMessage. However, in this case I would need to loop through the string to wrap all the integers in {} first, and then create a new Object[] with the first value blank. This is the output from running the above examples:

Name = 2 OR Name = 3 OR Name = 2

Name = 1 OR Name = 3 OR Name = 1

Does anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: Is this a homework problem or similar where you have to use that syntax, or do you have flexibility to modify it?

Comment: take a look at this replace all i made. you might find your solution in there :) http://fiddle.re/m4cke  make sure you click the java button when you use that link.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @chrylis, It's not homework, so I have full flexibility. :)
The strings will all be user generated via a UI. I need to write a method that will safely do the swap for any strings. There will be a maximum of 10 strings to replace, hence the comment about looping from 10 to 1.
If the user does not enter a string for advanced, I just concatenate the filters together. If they do provide the advanced string, I need to do the replace safely.
I need to read up on regular expressions, as they're not something I'm comfortable with.

Comment: @AlexChard I'd really recommend changing the strings so that you can use something like `FormatMessage`. This is tricky and annoying to get right; easier to use someone else's working version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions (`Pattern`):

```
public static String format(String input, String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int nr = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
        if (nr <= args.length) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(args[nr - 1]));
        }
    }

    matcher.appendTail(sb);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

A good tutorial concerning regular expressions in Java can be found here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html

Comment: I have no idea how to even read that. :( Time for some studying of regular expressions. :) Thanks for the reply, I'll try it while reading up on regexs.

Comment: I have tested it briefly, and it works for the basic example I've given above. I'll spend some time understanding it on Monday, while reading up on regexs in general. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've added a link to a good tutorial. Also note that I changed the source code slightly (simplification)!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now.
The only bit I don't understand is what Matcher.quoteReplacement does. I read the docs, but they didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, may be something like

```
String s = "1 OR 2 AND 3";
s=s.replace("1","Name=1");
s=s.replace("2","Name=2");
s=s.replace("3","Name=3");
```

I am not sure if this what you want, though.